# Windows IoT - logging activities in C#

Tags: c#, logging, iot, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

for my schoolproject i tried to communicate from my raspberry with Windows iot to a pc over TCP- sockets. All works fine but i want to log the traffic an also realise if something goes wrong.

So I programmed this LogFilewriter:

```
 public static void write(string message)
    {           

            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("\\" + "log.txt"))
            {
                logging(message, w);
            }

    }
    public static void logging(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
        w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, DateTime.Now.Date);
        w.WriteLine("  :");
        w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
        w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    }
```

The Problem is that if i call Log.write(message)   - (Log is the class) it throws following Exception:

> Blockquote
>   Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll

Has somebody an idea why this exception is thrown?

Comment: TextWriter is used in other parts of the class? Why you don't use an existing log?

Comment: I have to split it because this is for comercial use later on - an user should be able to read de specific log then.                                                                 However I tried to go to this path because i thought of this is unprotected....but it isn't :      `using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("c$\\Users\\Public\\log.txt"))
                {
                    logging(message, w);
                }`

Comment: Where (on which path) does your "logging" exe run?

Comment: Running in the standard debug folder from Visual Studio on the Pi.

Comment: Why did you write "\\log.txt? Just write "log.txt" and the log file should appear in the same folder of the .exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it the same as normal windows? You cannot write into the same folder as your EXE because permissions doesn't allow it. Either that or it is because the app is sandboxed.

I think this explains it?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67e9d61c-ccb6-47e4-8c7a-968166701920/c-write-to-file-on-windows-10-iot?forum=WindowsIoT

It says this,

*I think you're supposed to work with StorageFile and StorageFolder for UWP applications. We used them and had no issues so far. When I tried to work with the File class in the first release, it wasn't available at all.*

*Maybe this changed now. Try saving the file in your file in the "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\YOURPACKAGE". The application should have access there and maybe you can use the File class then.*

Read the whole thing because it also mentions that the file IO is sandboxed, and provides this link to suggest how to write to a file,

http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=554

Answer (score 0):

Streamwriter with true, will append the content to file

```
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("\\" + "log.txt", true))
           {logging(message, w);}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work - can't convert String into IOStream.

Comment: hmm, leme try again - It was pseudo. Will fire up my IoT when I reach my workshop

Comment: Thank you - i can't get this work ....always this Unauthorized Access Exception....